# How do I iterate over all the key value pairs recursively in a R list and modify a value?

Tags: r, list, replace

I want to modify the values of a list recursively based on some condition.

```
mylist = list(a = "test1", 
              b = list(bb = "test2", list(bbb = "test1")), 
              c = "test2")
```

I would like to modify the value if it is **test1** and replace it in this list or create a new list. E.g if the modification was to replace **test1** with **best1**, the resultant list should be

```
mylist = list(a = "best1", 
              b = list(bb = "test2", list(bbb = "best1")), 
              c = "test2")
```

What is the cleanest way to do this in R?

Comment: Try: `rapply(mylist, function(i) ifelse(i == "test1", "best1", i), how = "replace")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `rapply`

```
out <- rapply(mylist, function(x) replace(x, x == "test1", "best1"), how = "replace")
```

Check the output

```
identical(out, 
          list(a = "best1", 
               b = list(bb = "test2", list(bbb = "best1")), 
               c = "test2"))
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**:
My original answer(below) `unlist`s . However, we can use `purrr` and `plyr` to achieve a list-like replacement:

```
plyr::llply(purrr::flatten(mylist),
            function(x) ifelse(x=="test1","best1",x))

$a
[1] "best1"

$bb
[1] "test2"

[[3]]
    bbb 
"best1" 

$c
[1] "test2"
```

**Original**:

We can use:

```
lapply(Map(unlist,mylist),function(x) ifelse(x=="test1","best1",x))
$a
[1] "best1"

$b
     bb     bbb 
"test2" "best1" 

$c
[1] "test2"
```